# Search a datatable with loop and copy selected rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a datatable with string values, which I want to search for a specific value which I select from a dropdown menu. All matching values should be copied to another worksheet.

My code doesn't work. I dug through lots of stuff, but I am not able to figure out the problem.

```
Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'data copied from
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet 'data copied to
Dim abhaengigkeit As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'row counter

'sets vars
Set datasheet = Tabelle1
Set reportsheet = Tabelle44
abhaengigkeit = datasheet.Range("L3").Value

'goto datasheet and search and copy
datasheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

'loop to find records
For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 15) = abhaengigkeit Then
    ''Copy Soll''
        Range(Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, 23)).Copy      'copy column 1 to 10
        reportsheet.Select 'goto reportsheet (Aenderungsfortpflanzung)
        Range("A150").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste 
under last entry
        datasheet.Select
    End If
Next i
```

My datasheet (Tabelle1) is where the dropdown and the datatable is. The reportsheet is my destination sheet to copy the matching results.

Cell L3 is the Dropdown menu, my datatable loop should run through column P and copy all values which are stated in the following 8 columns.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work - do you get an error message - on what line? Does this even compile? It looks like your trying to use the worksheet names as variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
    Dim abhaengigkeit As String
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1") '<== I have set this up as sheet names not code names
    Set reportsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle44")
    abhaengigkeit = datasheet.Range("L3").Value

    With datasheet
        finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim unionRng As Range

        For i = 2 To finalrow
            If Cells(i, 15) = abhaengigkeit Then '<column 0
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Range(.Cells(i, 16), .Cells(i, 23))) ' 'P to W
                Else
                    Set unionRng = .Range(.Cells(i, 16), .Cells(i, 23))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

    End With

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
       If IsEmpty(reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp)) And reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
            unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A1")
        Else
            unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the actual sheet names?

Comment: Thanks so much! But i have a minor problem when running your stated code. I always get a "Subscript out of range (Error 9)" when the datasheet and reportsheet is set.

The spelling is right, and i already tried it like this: Workbooks("nameoffile.xls").Sheets("Tabelle1") Or
Workbooks("nameoffile.xls").Sheets("nameofsheet")

Any hints there?

Comment: If you have changed the [sheet code names](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) then you can say where ever it says datasheet simply say Tabelle1 e.g. Tabelle1.Range("L3").Value and same for reportsheet, simply replace with Tabelle44.

Comment: What are the names of the two sheets and are they in the same workbook as the code?

Comment: The actual sheet names are "Reifegrade" and "Aenderungsfortpflanzung". They are in the same workbook on different sheets. I tried replacing the datasheet/reportsheet with the explicit sheets (Tabelle1, Tabelle 44), but it's not doing anything then. When i try to debugg it seems like the loop doesnt start at all..

Comment: Put the actual names in. For example, if datasheet is Reifegrade then Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reifegrade") etc

Comment: Step through with F8 , what is the value of finalrow? Is the loop entered? What is the value of unionRng.Address?

Comment: Finalrow: -4162
Loop entered: No, skips after first line
unionRng= nothing

Think finalrow is the problem, or? My datatable is at collum P, which should be .Rows.Count, 15 or?

Comment: So how have you got -4162, that is definitely a problem!

Comment: What is  Debug.Print  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reifegrade") .Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reifegrade") .Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Address ? Or change to appropriate sheet name.

Comment: Sorry -4162 is the value of "End(xlUp).Row". The value vor finalrow is "0" at the beginning and "1" as soon as line of the loop is hit..

Comment: It implies no data in column 15 of the sheet it is working off. Verify the correct sheet is being used for lastrow and that it has data in column 15.

Comment: great, turns out that colum P is the value 16 ;)

But there is another small problem: It always copies and overrrides the values in the first row of the reportsheet. Regardless is there already are some values in there? Thanks so much again!

Comment: It shouldn't. What is the value of reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Address ? Or however it is renamed? Is it working with the right sheet and column?

Comment: If there are zero or one existing rows in the repotsheet, reportsheet.Range("A150") always shows 1. If there is more than one value, it shows the correct value..

Comment: That is correct. You are pasting to this point so if there are no rows currently populated you want to paste to the first row, otherwise to the next available row.

Comment: If you test with the workbook I supplied, it always adds to the next available row.

Comment: How did that go?

Comment: Tried to paste all my data in your file, but it is still not really working. Sometimes it just overrides the entry, sometimes it doesnt copy anything... I uploaded my file here https://ufile.io/p3gpr

Comment: Applied and tested --> Works like a charm! You saved my weekend, thanks so much!